# Dart language auto style fix tool?

Tags: dart

Is there any utility or any package to automatically fix dart style?

For example in C++, [ClangFormat](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html) automatically fix indentations, line length and other style nits.

Answer (score 3):

`dartformat` (or `dartfmt`) (https://github.com/dart-lang/dart_style) is part of the Dart SDK. `dartformat -w lib` in your project directory should do it for your `lib` directory. WebStorm has a format source feature which uses `dartformat` since a while.